# when performing testing, I have `Bucket name not specified or invalid` error after initialize the app in Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I know there are a lot of similar thread discussing similar issue, but I still don't find any solution because maybe my case is slightly different.

so I have this error when performing testing using Mocha in Firebase emulator

> Error: Bucket name not specified or invalid. Specify a valid bucket
> name via the storageBucket option when initializing the app, or
> specify the bucket name explicitly when calling the getBucket()
> method.

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
export const app = admin.initializeApp();
const storage = app.storage();
const defaultBucket = storage.bucket(); // it seem error is in here
```

I am using cloud function, so I assume `initializeApp()` with empty argument is fine according to [the documentation in here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters). but I have that error when run the test in emulator

my mocha test script is like this

```
export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8080" && export FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9099" && mocha -r ts-node/register src/tests/cloud_function_tests --recursive --extension .test.ts --timeout 60000 --exit
```

and it seems that error only appears when I perform the testing, if I run those code above using emulator (without mocha testing), that error will never occured

I am using

- Node 14
- firebase-admin: 9.6.0
- firebase-functions: 3.13.2
- firebase tools: 9.10.0

Comment: I got the same error since I updated my npm packages to the latest version :(